# Python Selenium - How to terminate unsuccessfully spawned Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, spawn

The following line of code is executed in my Python script:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

This line may either fail or succeed, depending on apparently random conditions (It is due to an extension that is being loaded, but that is not relevant here).

The problem is that even if this line fails, and raises a `WebDriverException`, an instance of Chromium will still be spawned, eventually flooding my entire desktop because I am running this line in a while loop until it works.

The following block of code does not work because driver is not defined.

```
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options = chrome_options)
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()
```

How to do this in a clever way?

Comment: By default, Chrome is attached to the chromedriver and whenever chromedriver is killed - Chrome would be automatically killed. What kind of `WebDriverException` is raised in your case? Thanks.

Comment: WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extensions://lotsofcharacters/_generated_background_page.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ah, are you also loading a custom extension?

Comment: Yes, ModHeader.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you have the following line :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

And this line may either `fail` or `succeed`. So there are 2 usecases which can be addressed as follows :

- **`Success`** : Incase the above mentioned line of code is `Success` we will use `driver.quit()` straight away as follows :

  ```
  try:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options = chrome_options)
      #other code
      driver.quit()
  ```
- **`Failure`** : Incase the above mentioned line of code is `Failure` we will use the [**taskkill**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command from [**os**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) module to force-kill the **`chromedriver`** `process` straight away as follows :

  ```
  import os
  #other code
  try:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options = chrome_options)
      #other code
      driver.quit()
  except WebDriverException:
          os.system("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe")
  ```

---

### Trivia

Through the command `webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options = chrome_options)` irrespective of whether `Chromium`session is spawned or not, a separate `chromedriver` session will be always spawned which we have taken care in our code. If you want to kill the `Chromium`session as well, you have to add the following line as well :

```
os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe")
```

Comment: What if other independent chromedriver instances that I don't want to terminate are running at the same time?

Comment: @user3257755 Then we have to extract the PID and kill the process through PID which is out of scope for this question. Please Accept the Answer.